# Как присвоить переменной значение коллбэка?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
var course_code;

function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  script.onload = function() {
    typeof window[callback] === 'function' ? window[callback]() : console.error("Error: function name is not defined");
  }
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Далее когда я делаю вот так, то course_code становится undefined:

```
course_code = loadScript("url", "function_name");
```

Comment: Почему callback  у вас в string? Он разве не должен быть функцией?

Comment: Не должен быть: мы функцию вызываем через window. Это нужно будет потом, когда я доделаю скрипт. А сейчас нужно вверять значение коллбэка.

Answer (score 1):

Тернарный оператор это не просто сокращённая запись if. Он ещё возврщает результат и этот результат может быть присвоен.

```
var callbackResult = (typeof window[callback] === 'function') ? window[callback]() : null;
```

Так как `script.onload` выполняется асинхронно, то ваша функция loadScript завершится до того, как скрип загрузится. Поэтому сразу это значение вы вернуть не можете. Но вы можете пообещать его вернуть. Такое обещание называется [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).